# Cannot start a service instance in Virtuoso-opensource

Tags: cmd, open-source, virtuoso

I'm trying to create and start the service instance. But it doesn't start.
Here is the command I ran:

```
virtuoso-t +service start +instance MyService
```

Here my output:

```
The Virtuoso_MyService service is being started
```

But the `localhost:8890` cannot be loaded.

**Details:**

- Opened CMD as administrator.
- Ran the same commands 3 days back and the services were running fine till I restarted the system.
- Commands followed.

  ```
  C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\MyWork\virtuoso-opensource\bin>virtuoso-t +service create +instance MyService +configfile ..\database\virtuoso.ini

  [Using virtuoso.ini in C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\MyWork\virtuoso-opensource\database]
  The Virtuoso_MyService service has been registered
    and is associated with the executable 

  C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\MyWork\virtuoso-opensource\bin\virtuoso-t.exe

  C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\MyWork\virtuoso-opensource\bin>virtuoso-t +service start +instance MyService
  The Virtuoso_MyService service is being started

  C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\MyWork\virtuoso-opensource\bin>virtuoso-t +service list +instance MyService
  MyService            Stopped
  ```

As suggested by @TallTed, I have added the log:

```
            Wed Mar 01 2017
16:27:37 { Loading plugin 1: Type `plain', file `wikiv' in `../hosting'
16:27:37   WikiV version 0.6 from OpenLink Software
16:27:37   Support functions for WikiV collaboration tool
16:27:37   SUCCESS plugin 1: loaded from ..\hosting\wikiv.dll }
16:27:37 { Loading plugin 2: Type `plain', file `mediawiki' in `../hosting'
16:27:37   MediaWiki version 0.1 from OpenLink Software
16:27:37   Support functions for MediaWiki collaboration tool
16:27:37   SUCCESS plugin 2: loaded from ..\hosting\mediawiki.dll }
16:27:37 { Loading plugin 3: Type `plain', file `creolewiki' in `../hosting'
16:27:37   CreoleWiki version 0.1 from OpenLink Software
16:27:37   Support functions for CreoleWiki collaboration tool
16:27:37   SUCCESS plugin 3: loaded from ..\hosting\creolewiki.dll }
16:27:37 { Loading plugin 4: Type `plain', file `im' in `../hosting'
16:27:37   IM version 0.6 from OpenLink Software
16:27:37   Support functions for Image Magick 6.6.7
16:27:37   SUCCESS plugin 4: loaded from ..\hosting\im.dll }
16:27:37 { Loading plugin 5: Type `plain', file `wbxml2' in `../hosting'
16:27:37   WBXML2 version 0.9 from OpenLink Software
16:27:37   Support functions for WBXML2 0.10.7 Library
16:27:37   SUCCESS plugin 5: loaded from ..\hosting\wbxml2.dll }
16:27:37 Unable to create file virtuoso.lck (File exists).
16:27:37 This probably means you either do not have permission to start
16:27:37 this server, or that virtuoso-t is already running.
16:27:37 If you are absolutely sure that this is not the case, please try
16:27:37 to remove the file virtuoso.lck and start again.
```

Comment: Have you looked to `C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\MyWork\virtuoso-opensource\database\virtuoso.log` for any error or other messages?

Comment: @TallTed i have added the log. I can see the problem and tried to remove the already existing virtuoso.lck file. And it worked.
Thank you. It was a great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the Virtuoso log file --

```
16:27:37 Unable to create file virtuoso.lck (File exists).
16:27:37 This probably means you either do not have permission to start
16:27:37 this server, or that virtuoso-t is already running.
16:27:37 If you are absolutely sure that this is not the case, please try
16:27:37 to remove the file virtuoso.lck and start again.
```

Removing the `virtuoso.lck` as advised there should resolve the issue.

In a normal shutdown, Virtuoso will clean up this file.  If power is cycled, or the Virtuoso process is otherwise uncleanly terminated, this file may linger, as in this case, and so need to be manually removed.

The [Virtuoso website](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) has a vast amount of information, including the [official Virtuoso manual](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/) and the [evolving docs, covering Open Source in more detail](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSIndex#Download,%20Build,%20and%20Use%20--%20Get%20Started!).

ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.

Comment: I have just started to learn virtuoso. Can you please suggest some good source that provides some hands on example. Thank you.

Comment: @KrishnaChouhan - see edited answer, with several links

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues on windows 10. I fixed by going to my

```
C:\Program Files\OpenLink Software\Virtuoso OpenSource 7.2\database
```

and manually delete **virtuoso.lck** file

The restart my server and everything now started working fine!